# How to fix 400 Bad request error in Nestjs

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, rest, nestjs

When I call a nestjs api, everytime it return the 400 error bad request,

the controller is this

```js
@Roles(Role.Supplier)
  @Get("reviews-with-answers")
  async getAllReviewsWithAnswers(
    @Query("organisationId", ParseIntPipe) organisationId: number,
  ) {
    return this.reviewService.getAllReviewsWithAnswers(organisationId);
  }
```

and the service is this

get all reviews with their answers

```js
  async getAllReviewsWithAnswers(organisationId: number) {
    const response = await this.prisma.review.findMany({
      where: { organisationId },
      select: { id: true, text: true },
    });
    return response;
  }
```

I want that it return the review data.